# Confirming document upload in couchbase

Tags: java, android, mobile, couchbase

I am creating an app that logs data. I am creating documents that have the data and sending those documents to a couchbase server. Or I am trying to anyways. One major concern I have is how do I confirm a document is stored on the server so that it can be immediately deleted on the device? I am hoping there is a quick and efficient way to do this. The end result is to have a thread constantly checking if there is a connection to couchbase, and if so start sending data up to clear it off the device. Most documentation seems to be regarding syncying the database, however I don't want to do this because I don't want to keep a copy of the data on the device. It would take up too much storage. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: For clarification, I currently have the app storing many data points in documents. I want to send these documents to a couchbase server. I don't want to "sync" the documents, but rather just insert them into the database then immediately delete them off the device. How would one go about doing this? Most examples I have seen typically sync documents such as profile information where changes can be made in various synced databases and all those changes would appear in every database. Instead I want a 1 way relationship with the database were information is sent, confirmed as received, then immediately deleted from the device.

Comment: Are you using Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway?

Comment: @MatthewGroves I have currently only written the code that manages the couchbase light database on the phone. So as of right now the device can log and store data points on the device. I am researching how to get this data to the server, however everything I see references sync gateway. My understanding of the sync gateway is it syncs the two databases, the one on the device and the server. This isn't what I want because once the server has a copy I don't need that data on the device anymore. 

I don't know what other functionalities Sync gateway has as I see it only being used one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a few possibilities.

If you are expecting a solid network connection, or are ok with handling errors yourself, you can achieve this with a direct REST call to Sync Gateway.  You can, of course, always write your own REST server that talks directly to Couchbase Server, too.

The second way relies on an older version of Couchbase Lite.  Couchbase Lite 2.x is a major rewrite of the product.  As of the current shipping version (2.1), it does not support this approach, so you'll need to use the 1.x version (1.3 or later, IIRC).  See further down for how to approach this with 2.1.

Set up a push only replication.  After replication, cycle through the docs and purge all the ones that are not still pending.  (This uses the `isDocumentPending` method on the `Replication` class.  That's the key piece not available as of 2.1.) You can either run one shot replications and do this after the replication completes, or monitor the replication state of a continuous replication.

Purging a document from the local CB Lite database effectively makes it act as if it never existed on that device.  By running a push only replication, you don't have to worry about the docs getting sent back to the device.

Using 2.1, you can't as easily determine if a document has been replicated.  So you need to run a replication to completion while avoiding a race condition with writing something new.

One approach here is to pause writing documents, run a one shot replication, then purge the documents before starting up again.  You could also work out something with alternating databases, or tracking documents yourself somehow, etc.

For completeness, if you were in a situation where you had a mixed use, that is, wanted only some documents pushed up off the device and forgotten, and some synced, you would control this through Sync Gateway channels.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Lite and Sync Gateway well enough, but from a Server perspective:

You could use the new Eventing service in Couchbase. When a document is created in bucket A, you could write an event to copy that document over to bucket B. Then, if the documents are deleted on the device, it wouldn't matter if they get deleted from bucket A.

I have a bucket "staging" and a bucket "final". I created a function called "moveIt" with "final" (I aliased as 'f').

[image: Creating a 'moveit' function in Couchbase Eventing]

The OnUpdate function could be as simple as:

```
function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    f[meta.id] = doc;
}
```

My main concern would be the timing. I don't think there's an easy way for your mobile app to know that the event has finished copying a document before you decide to delete it in Lite and start a Sync. But it might be worth a try. Check out the docs to [learn more about the Eventing service details](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/eventing/eventing-overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Couchbase Lite 2.5, you can use [replicated events](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.5/swift.html#replication-events) to detect when a document has synced (pushed to server or pulled from server). You can register a callback on the Couchbase Lite replicator to detect if the documents have been pushed to the sync gateway and then use the [purge API](https://docs.couchbase.com/mobile/2.5.0/couchbase-lite-swift/Classes/Database.html#/s:18CouchbaseLiteSwift8DatabaseC13purgeDocument6withIDySS_tKF) to locally purge